# Django REST Framework - Relationships between nested object lists

Tags: python, json, django, rest

I couldn't find an answer to this problem online. That said, I am new to building REST APIs and may be doing something fundamentally incorrect.

What I'd like to do is POST a JSON object with characteristics like this:

```
{
"groceryStoreVisit": 100,
"fruits": [
    {"id":10, "type":"apple", "quantity":4},
    {"id":20, "type":"orange", "quantity":3},
    {"id":30, "type":"banana", "quantity":6}
],
"nuts": [
    {"id":40, "type":"cashew", "no_bags":2},
    {"id":50, "type":"peanut", "no_bags":4}
],
"bags": [
    {"id":0, "type":"paper", "contents":[10,20,30]},
    {"id":1, "type":"plastic", "contents":[40,50]}
]}
```

My issue is that, upon trying to serialize the data, I'm getting an error like this:

> {"bags":[{"fruits":["Object with id=10 does not exist."]}]}

My **Bag** serialization class looks like this:

```
class BagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contents = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, queryset=Fruit.objects.all(), slug_field='id')
    class Meta:
        model = Bag
        fields = ('id', 'type', 'contents')
```

My **GroceryStoreVisit** (entire object) serialization class looks like this:

```
class GroceryStoreVisitSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fruits = FruitSerializer(many=True)
    bags = BagSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = GroceryStoreVisit
        fields = ('groceryStoreVisit', 'fruits', 'nuts', 'bags')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        fruits_data = validated_data.pop('fruits')
        nuts_data = validated_data.pop('nuts')
        bags_data = validated_data.pop('bags')
        groceryStoreVisit = GroceryStoreVisit.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for fruit_data in fruits_data:
            Fruit.objects.create(groceryStoreVisit=groceryStoreVisit, **fruit_data)

        for nut_data in nuts_data:
            Nut.objects.create(groceryStoreVisit=groceryStoreVisit, **nut_data)

        for bag_data in bags_data:
            Bag.objects.create(groceryStoreVisit=groceryStoreVisit, **bag_data)

        return groceryStoreVisit
```

I'm not sure if this is enough information to give the picture about what I'm trying to accomplish. There's nothing exotic about the models or Fruit/Nut serializers. Please let me know if there's anything I can clarify to make the problem definition more comprehensible.

I want to validate that the Bag contents exist within the top-level GroceryStoreVisit object. Can I do this as I'm trying to?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `SlugRelatedField` tries to lookup the matching `Fruit` objects before you even have a chance to create them. This happens in `to_internal_value()` which is called before `create()` to obtain `validated_data`. Can the `contents` part reference existing fruits or only those that are part of the current message?

Comment: For now, I only need `contents` to part reference `fruits` of the current message. Eventually, I'd like to allow `contents` to reference existing or parts of the current message, but not a priority now.

Comment: @dhke Might there be a way to override the `to_internal_value()` method? I tend to want to avoid messing with the advanced mechanics but I'm wondering if there's a smart solution for this particular case.

Comment: @TomChristie I'm just going to throw this up to you. I'm sure you get a lot of questions directed your way, but I'm really struggling with this problem. Any help would be much appreciated!